# Doubt on evaluation of limits using squeeze theorem /sandwich theorem

Tags: limits, limits-without-lhopital

Can we use sandwich theorem in the following situation :

If
$$f(x)< g(x) \le h(x),$$

$$ \lim_{x \to a}f(x) =  \lim_{x \to a}h(x) = p $$

Can one say $$\lim_{x \to a}g(x) = p$$ ??

Comment: Did you mean $\lim_{x \rightarrow a}f(x) = \lim_{x \rightarrow a}h(x) = p$ and can one say $\lim_{x \rightarrow a}g(x) = p$?

Comment: yea , i ve made the correction.Thanks !

Comment: I guess you still should have $\lim_{x \rightarrow a}f(x) = \lim_{x \rightarrow a}h(x) = p$

Comment: Yes!! In the statement of Squeeze theorem the inequalities can be weak or strong. It does not matter.

Answer (score 2):

One can say that because if $a<b$ then surely $a\le b$.